# Doctrine: Multiple json_contains requests in one where clause

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

i try to solve the following problem:

I want to fetch notifications filtered by mandant AND roles of the User. The user could only have 1 Mandant and multiple roles.

The roles field in the DB contains a json array with the roles that should read the notification.

I have an Array with the roles of the actual user:

`$roles= array('role1','role2','role3')`

Now i need to do something like this:

```
select *
from notification
where (mandant_id = 'xxxxx' or mandant_id is null)
AND (JSON_CONTAINS(roles, '\"role1\"', '$') = 1 OR JSON_CONTAINS(roles, '\"role3\"', '$') = 1)
ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10
```

the mandant part is easy:

```
$queryBuilder->where('notification.mandantId = :mandantId OR notification.mandantId is null');
$queryBuilder->setParameter('mandantId', $userMandantId, MandantIdDoctrineType::NAME);
```

now i need to loop over the array $roles and put the querys in one where clause combined with OR.

I need a loop like:

```
foreach($roles AS $role){
  ....build up the query sting....
}
```

with the result like:

```
$qb->andWhere(JSON_CONTAINS(roles, '\"role1\"', '$') = 1 OR JSON_CONTAINS(roles, '\"role3\"', '$') = 1)
```

couldnt find the right way. please help me out! :)

Comment: I think your question title may be off since you demonstrate yourself that you know how to chain clauses in a single where. Am I correct in the assumption that what you want to know is how to use JSON_CONTAINS with doctrine? If so, you need an extension - have a look here: https://github.com/ScientaNL/DoctrineJsonFunctions

Comment: got that already. but no i need to put/chain the request comming from the loop .. if you could follow. i try to modify the title

Comment: @bananaapple i modified the title and made some more codeexamples in the text.

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
$roles            = ['role1', 'role2', 'role3'];
$roleQueryParts = [];

$i = 0;
foreach ($roles as $role) {
    ++$i;

    // build the individual conditionals of your OR chain
    $roleQueryParts[] = "JSON_CONTAINS(roles, :role$i, '$') = 1";

    // set the role parameters - note we're passing them as strings wrapped in "
    $queryBuilder->setParameter('role' . $i, '"' . $role . '"');
}

// fuse the conditionals into one string of condition 1 OR condition 2 OR...
$roleQuery = implode(' OR ', $roleQueryParts);

$queryBuilder->andWhere($roleQuery);
```

You may need to put the `setParameter()` bit into its own `foreach` after the `andWhere()` - I can't recall if Doctrine will let you set parameters before you added them to the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

thx @bananaapple you made my day.

It worked great, expept the second loop i had to put in and reposisioning the ->andWhere Query.

```
$roles            = ['role1', 'role2', 'role3'];
$roleQueryParts = [];

$i = 0;
foreach ($roles as $role) {
    ++$i;

    // build the individual conditionals of your OR chain
    $roleQueryParts[] = "JSON_CONTAINS(roles, :role$i, '$') = 1";

}

// fuse the conditionals into one string of condition 1 OR condition 2 OR...
$roleQuery = implode(' OR ', $roleQueryParts);

// fire the query
$queryBuilder->andWhere($roleQuery);

$i = 0;
foreach ($roles as $role) {
    ++$i;

    // set the role parameters - note we're passing them as strings wrapped in "
    $queryBuilder->setParameter('role' . $i, '"' . $role . '"');

}
```

That worked great for me. Thank u!